# Get "id" part of outlook emai

Tags: javascript, outlook

Just a quick question, how would you go about getting the "id" from this URL:

> https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/id/AQQkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xZGUwLTNjMTAtMDACLTAwCgAQAB%2FnQ1lgT6dDlqIakp3j4qk%3D

These URLs change alot, but i just want the message id.

Its not just a query param, so i can't just go and get it from there.

How would i do this?

Comment: @showdev there can also be new parts to the URL, including query param in some cases, that of would break it.

Comment: In what ways might the URL change? What are the criteria? What have you tried? What goes wrong?

Comment: I have no idea, but i have seen links with different parts. I can't recreate them, but i know that it happens to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just split the URL by `/` and get the 8th index, and if there is parameters, just split it by `?` and get the first index

```js
const url = 
'https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/id/AQQkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xZGUwLTNjMTAtMDACLTAwCgAQAB%2FnQ1lgT6dDlqIakp3j4qk%3D?a=1&'
let url_split = url.split('/')

let id_with_parameter = url_split[7]
let id = id_with_parameter.split('?')[0]

console.log(id)
```

Output `AQQkADAwATM0MDAAMS0xZGUwLTNjMTAtMDACLTAwCgAQAB%2FnQ1lgT6dDlqIakp3j4qk%3D`

This probably has a lot of limitation and not the best way